# how do you start an express server with react on heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have managed to get my app working on heroku and I can hit the url and it loads successfully.

the problem is this is just the React frontend (locally I fire up on port 3000). I then also use an express node server as my backend for my api end points and then firebase as my data. when running locally I have been firing it up on 3007. however, I've just deployed and it's running the frontend but none of the API calls are being made (I presume it has not started the server)

how can I link the 2 up or tell heroku to run the other server command as well?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have folder structured

```
-main folder
--client folder
--server stuff
```

try writing in server's package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  }
```

then deploy project to heroku from server folder's level

this will build your client during the time you're deploying your whole project

@edit

also add

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  const path = require("path");
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

to server's index.js file

Comment: ok so where should my src/ folder live? I tried putting that all inside the client folder and it broke

Comment: ok I have it serving up my routes now on heroku but it wont load the frontend??